# How fix the header of the table having two headers row and scroll bar in body

Tags: css

I have the a table and wanted this as fixed header.
I have 2 headers row in this scenario.
Below is the attached html for the same

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">
                </th>
                <th colspan="3">
                    Header Row11
                </th>
                <th colspan="3">
                    Header Row12
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                    Header Row12
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                    Header Row14
                </th>
                <th colspan="1">
                </th>
                <th colspan="2">
                    Header Row15
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="submit" value="Remove" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row21
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row22
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row22
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row23
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row24
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row25
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row26
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row27
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row2
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row2
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row26
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row26
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row26
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row26
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row26
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row26
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header Row26
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < @Model.abc.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    .......... ................
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]

I wanted some what this kinda of table.
Please suggest me on how to achieve so.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get away with just using CSS on this one... https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/index.html

Comment: You could do this is by having the header be a separate element, instead of making it an actual part of the table.